# Pure css fixed header table example broken in IE9

Tags: html, css, scroll, internet-explorer-9, css-tables

If you go to the following example on Chrome or Firefox, and then in IE9, you will see that it is broken in IE9:

http://www.imaputz.com/cssStuff/bigFourVersion.html

I can fix the height by giving a width to the table rows, but is there anyway to bring the scroll bar back?

I'm probably going to reimplement my table using divs if I don't find a reasonable solution...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like a common issue.
This question is related to your issue: [IE9 + css : problem with fixed header table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6903498/ie9-css-problem-with-fixed-header-table)

Comment: I found that issue before opening my question.  It only resolves the height problem (which I've been able to fix).  But the problem is the scroll bar doesn't show up.