# Issue to scroll tbody on IE 9 (tbody's height = height-line)

Tags: html, css, scroll, html-table, internet-explorer-9

Sorry for my bad English, I hope you're going to understand what I want to say...

I'm trying to implement an HTML table which support scrolling of table bodies independently of the table head.

I found the following question which helped me a lot :
[How to scroll table's "tbody" independent of "thead"?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8321849/how-to-scroll-tables-tbody-independent-of-thead)

I tested the following code, it works on Chrome (22), Firefox (16) and Opera (12) without issue :

**HTML :**

```
<table>
  <thead>
   <tr>
    <th>Title1</th>
    <th>Title2</th>
    <!-- ... -->
   </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
   <tr>
     <td>...</td>
     <td>...</td>
     <!-- ... -->
   </tr>
   <!-- ... -->
  </tbody>
</table>
```

**CSS :**

```
thead, tbody {
    display: block;
}

tbody {
    height:500px;
    overflow-y:auto;
    overflow-x:hidden;
}

thead {
    line-height: 20px;
}
```

So it works on the main browsers except IE 9, on IE, I have some issues :

- The tbody's height is not defined (so I don't have any scrollbar)
- Each  has an height of 500px (the tbody's height on other browsers)

The two following examples have exactly the same issues : http://jsfiddle.net/nyCKE/2/ , http://www.imaputz.com/cssStuff/bigFourVersion.html

I saw the following question (and answer) but it doesn't help me : [IE9 + css : problem with fixed header table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6903498/ie9-css-problem-with-fixed-header-table)

So I'm sure that the bug comes from IE but I don't have any idea how to fix it without change my HTML structure.

Have someone any idea ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I have slightly tried to fix it. Hope it gives some idea

HTML

```
<div class="wrap">
    <div class="inner">
        <table>
            <thead><tr>
                <th><p>Problem</p></th>
                <th><p>Solution</p></th>
        </tr>               
            </thead>            
            <tbody>              
            </tbody>
        </table>
    </div>
</div>​
```

CSS

```
p {margin:0 0 1em}
table p {margin :0}
.wrap {
    margin:50px 0 0 2%;
    float:left;
    position:relative;
    height:200px;
    overflow:hidden;
    padding:25px 0 0;
    border:1px solid #000;
width:150px
}
.inner {
    padding:0 ; 
    height:200px;
    overflow:auto;
}    
table {  margin:0 0 0 -1px; border-collapse:collapse; width:130px}
td {
    padding:5px;
    border:1px solid #000;
    text-align:center;    
}
thead th {
    font-weight:bold;
    text-align:center;
    border:1px solid #000;
    padding:0 ;    
    color:#000;
}
thead th {border:none;}
thead tr p {  position:absolute;   top:0;    }
.last { padding-right:15px!important; }​
```

Demo http://jsfiddle.net/nyCKE/272/

Comment: Thank you ! It works, there is only one issue. With that solution, only the `<p>` on `<th>` is visible when we scroll. But I have to see the style of my `<th>` too (because I use `tableSorter` plugin), so I put the `absolute` value on my `<th>` directly, and I set my `left` CSS property with a jQuery function. It's not perfect (because it uses Javascript and I think it doesn't work without `border-collapse:collapse`), but it works on IE, I hope this bug will be fixed soon.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a shorter answer that allows you to scroll the table with a fixed header in ie9.

Add a conditional div around the table

```
<!--[if lte IE 9]>
<div class="old_ie_wrapper">
<!--<![endif]-->
<table>
...
<!--[if lte IE 9]>
</div>
<!--<![endif]-->
```

Add the following styles for ie9

```
    .old_ie_wrapper {
        height: 500px;
        overflow: auto;
    }

        .old_ie_wrapper tbody {
            height: auto;
        }

        .old_ie_wrapper thead tr {
            position: absolute;
        }

        .old_ie_wrapper tbody tr:first-child {
            height: 67px;
            vertical-align: bottom;
        }
```

You will have to adjust the heights and probably other properties based on your table.