# make html table <thead> fixed while scroll in dynamic <tbody> in php

Tags: php, html, css

I have dynamic table in php where `<tbody>` content dynamically fetched from database, i want to make `<thead>` fixed while scroll, my code work fine in static html `<tbody>`.

Here is my code

```
<div class="data">
  <table>
      <thead>
        <tr>
          <th>Page Id</th>
          <th>User Id</th>
          <th>Page Title</th>
        </tr>
      </thead>
      <?php
        foreach($this->analysisL as $key => $value) {?>
      <tbody>
        <tr>
          <td><?php echo $value['daily_clicks']?></td>
          <td><?php echo $value['RDCL']?></td>
          <td><?php echo $value['SDCL']?></td>

        </tr>
      </tbody>
      <?php }?>
    </table>
  </div>
```

Here is my css

```
body{
font-family: sans-serif;
}

h1{
font-size: 2em;
}

p{
margin-top: 1em;
}
div{
padding: 0 50px
}

.data{
position: fixed;
top: 0;  
z-index: 0;
}
.content{
position: relative;
background: #fff; 
z-index: 1;
padding: 50px;
}

th,td{
width: 200px;
padding: 3px;
}

th{
background: #ccc;
}
```

---

My Goal is to make table head fixed position while scroll and the content of table body dynamic fetching from database using php loop

Comment: remove fixed position from .data and add it to .data thead!

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12836651/issue-to-scroll-tbody-on-ie-9-tbodys-height-height-line

Answer (score 0):

I recommend you to use 'head fixer' js library (https://github.com/lai32290/TableHeadFixer)
fast and easy way to make table head/foot fixed.